Darwinian Free Will

Free will gives a creature the ability to make rational choices. [Premise]

A creature that has the ability to make rational choices can better access & utilize biotic (food, mates, friends, medicine) & abiotic resources (tool-making, fire, etc.). [Premise]

Better use of biotic & abiotic resources is an evolutionary advantage (more offspring). [Premise]

Free will is evolutionarily advantageous [Subconclusion: from 1, 2, 3]

Whatever is evolutionarily advantageous must have existed, exists, will exist. [Premise]

Free will must have existed, exists, will exist [Main conclusion: from 4, 5]


Question: How good is this scientific argument for free will?

Something giving an evolutionary advantage doesn't mean it exists, especially given that you haven't established that it's possible for it to exist yet, nor that it's a inheritable physical trait that can be selected for (required for evolution). If #1 is your definition of free will, then you've just defined free will into existence, and you don't really need this argument. If you're instead saying that free will is a thing that can give the ability to make rational choices, (a) why, and (b) that doesn't mean it's the only thing that can (which would be required for the argument to be valid).

If 5 was true we would all be X-men and travelling to other dimensions on our silver surf. Maybe some more nuanced formulation is necessary. Also, this argument for free will might be based on scientific results as premises, but is not scientific in itself. It's just a bunch of syllogisms.

@NotThatGuy, good points. would it be "easier" to create an illusion of free will (there are some folks who subscribe to this possibility) rather than authentic free will? Number 2, you correctly raised the issue of possibility; a person might be a self-made Einstein or Schwarzenneger, but the mechanism of inheritance doesn't allow (?) for vertical transmission of these traits. Number 3, am I conflating free will with intelligence? However, ignoring point number 3, anything that's gonna help make more babies will/should evolve, oui?

@armand, Nature probably isn't gunning for 100%. 60% - 90% freedom of will could hit the sweet spot of an evolutionarily successful species. The most "successful" species around is homo sapiens and they possess (a maya of) free will.

First, something that helps "make more babies" does not necessarily evolve. There has to be a pathway to it from the existing state through reasonably few random mutations, and for most somethings it does not exist. Second, you do assign to free will the job of intelligence, and in a deterministic world with no free will evolution of the latter would proceed just the same. Survival is enhanced by 'rational' responses, whether those are accompanied by free choices is moot. And yes, that evolution is not about the best but only "good enough" is a platitude among biologists.

@Conifold, veritas, there's got to be a pathway, but "everything" must be part of the evolutionary process i.e. the putative mechanism itself should evolve, like unlocking a feature or ability. If they entail violation of known chemical or physical laws, that's another story.

"Everything" is not part of evolution even without violating physical laws, biological constraints are much more stringent. DNA mutations are not a magic wand for unlocking wonders. They can induce incremental improvements, not redesign an organism to optimize fitness. This is why humans did not evolve wings, fish did not evolve jet engines, and no animals are powered by nuclear fission.

Agreed, there are constraints, but yet to see a physical/chemical law being overturned for biology. What of directed evolution (genetic engineering, etc.)? We do breed dogs/horses/cattle/pigs/sheep? Is this just speeding up and old car instead of switching to a "better" yana?

How do I improve the argument, if it all possible?

@armand, spot on! I haven't experimentally demonstrated the existence of free will (in the present) and haven't provided any evidence of free will (in the past) and too, have made no predictions in re free will (in the future). Is free will a scientific claim?

The animals we bred would never become as large / hairy / hairless / colors the animals can't themselves see etc. in the wild. We didn't "speed up" anything except for self-gratification.

@ScottRowe, we just tinkered around with trait combos, while depending entirely on natural reproduction to do its thing. Gregor Mendel & his peas.

@Hudjefa right, when I solder up a radio, I'm just using the natural properties of copper, silicon and things. I mean, radios would have happened eventually.

1 begs the question. 2-6 are unnecessary because 1 assumes that there is free will (that which is not, gives not).
5 is false. Being able to spawn healthy offspring which grew to adulthood in five minutes by saying "bippity boppity alakazam" would be evolutionarily advantageous. No such ability exists.

Pax vobis, deer can walk within 5 - 10 minutes of being born.

@Hudjefa and, their brains are proportionally much smaller. Humans have other ways to prevent their babies from being eaten by wolves or else we would all be Olympic runners instead of sitting here on this forum.

@ScottRowe, any specific reason why you believe free will is biologically asambhav (impossible)?

@Hudjefa no, because I do not have beliefs about free will.

Your premises are wildly unjustified.
Even if #1 didn't beg the question (as pointed out by others) ... it's also just a wild unfounded supposition.
Why should free-will (if it exists) be connected to rationality?
What is your basis for #2? why do you assert that isolated "rational choices" at an individual level result in the optimal usage of resources over a whole population/environment?
#5 is patently absurd, as has already been widely critiqued by others. Being beneficial neither causes it to be possible nor to exist if it is possible.

Intelligence/rationality helps us figure out what influences our decisions. Can we then free ourselves from these external forces? Je ne sais pas.

@Hudjefa at that point we would be changing ourselves, not evolving. Creating better medical equipment to perform safer surgery is not evolution. Changing some of our own traits is not evolution either.  All 'success' is not equivalent.

@Hudjefa I haven't the faintest idea what that comment is supposed to mean - it doesn't appear to connect to any of my answer?

@Brondahl, you say woof!, and I say meow! . Apologies. You queried me on what the link is between rationality & free will, and I tried to answer. It's foggy, it's dark, I don't have me glasses on. C'est la vie?

That is not an argument at all. Free will is not a theory that should be argued for or against. Free will is just a name given to a phenomenon, real or imaginary.
In your first "premise" you actually define free will as the ability to make rational choices. That is a good valid definition. Some people would say that it is the best of them all.
Do we have the ability to make rational choices? Answering or asking this or any other question is a rational choice.

Si, non liquet as to whether free will = intelligence/rationality.

If free will is "a name given to a phenomenon, real or imaginary", then surely one can argue for or against that phenomenon being real. Every concept in the English language is "just a name", and if that precludes us from arguing for or against it, we wouldn't be able to argue for or against anything.

Your final sentences ask a question and provide an answer without any evidence. It would be much more interesting if could say why you believe that asking a question is a rational choice as opposed to the illusion of a rational choice. This is, after all, kind of what is at issue in this thread; is free will real or illusory?

Cogito, Increase(Freedom) → Increase(Intelligence). Are philosophers freeer than the average Joe?

@NotThatGuy Are you willing to argue against  or even question the reality of our ability to make rational choices? Good luck with that.

@Futilitarian How can you ask a question without choosing the question? How can you answer a question without choosing the answer?

I seem to remember you defining free will as something like 'the ability to make decisions'. Sure. But what evidence do you have that your decisions aren't illusory? I'm not saying you're wrong. I'm merely pointing out that you can't possibly know for certain whether you're right or not. This is why the question of free will is still an open one; we at present have no way to know for sure. If you think you do know for certain, then the onus is on you to describe how you're sure.

@Futilitarian Making a decision and making a choice mean exactly the same: Deliberately selecting a course of action out of multiple options. How would you describe an illusory decision? Is it a decision made by someone else?

I totally agree with you about decisions and choices. I never claimed otherwise. An illusory decision is a circumstance in which you think you are making a decision, but in reality you are not in control of the path you 'choose'.  No actual decision is taking place. What you experience as a decision is in fact merely the unfolding of a causal or random series of events. We don't know of any other mechanisms.

@Futilitarian, the maya (illusion) of free(dom) will? The Owl of Minerva (re Hegel)?

@Futilitarian Why do you claim that "no actual decision is taking place"? That makes no sense. Every voluntary action must be decided. Only spinal reflexes are causal reactions to prior events, no decision is needed.

I never claimed no actual decision is taking place. I claim we don't know whether what we feel to be voluntary decisions are in fact voluntary. Any cursory reading of the literature reveals this. Again, if you claim to know one way or another, the burden of proof is on you. Simply making more assertions does nothing to progress the conversation.

@Hudjefa. I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean.

@Futilitarian What is an "involuntary decision"? Sounds like an oxymoron. Claiming that we don't know whether decisions are decisions or something else makes no sense and does nothing to progress the conversation.

Agreed. An involuntary decision is an oxymoron. A better term is 'illusory decision'. I'm not claiming to progress the conversation. You are making a claim that free will - as defined as the 'the ability to make decisions' - certainly exists. But you have yet to explain how you know this. No evidence proving free will or the lack of it - as far as I know - exists.

@Futilitarian Free will is not a theory or a claim that even could be proven or disproven. Free will is only a name given to a phenomenon. If you give the name to a known real phenomenon, there is no need to prove anything. If you give the name to an imaginary phenomenon, there is no need to disprove anything. If you feel that free will should be proven or disproven, that means that you have no definition at all, you have no idea what is the thing you call free will.

@Futilitarian. it's non liquet to me as well, but Hegel (history is grasped backwards and is a chronology of the progress of reason, the geist of libertas).  ???

On the contrary. I'm using your definition. Free will, according to such a definition, is neither proven or disproven. The literature contains a range of opinions. None have been conclusively proven. Your claim too, remains a claim without apparent evidence. I won't comment here any more unless some such evidence is forthcoming. All the best.

@Futilitarian The ability to make decisions is not a claim or a theory that should be proven or disproven. The ability to make decisions is a necessary requirement for doing anything. You cannot prove or disprove anything without the ability to decide what you are going to prove or disprove and how.

@PerttiRuismäki Plenty of things happen without making a decision.  Clouds dont decide to rain.  You cant just claim that proving or disproving things can only be done by decisions, you need to show more than that.  Really, it's just circular, since the only way you can "prove" that is by circling back to all mental actions being non-illusory decisions, which is the exact thing you need to prove; it cant be assumed here.

@JMac Anything you do voluntarily requires a decision from you. The fact that you are able to do something voluntarily (=not due to a physical cause or someone else's decision) proves that you are able to make decisions. What is an "illusory" decision? You have to first define this concept before we can discuss it.

@PerttiRuismäki But we are unable to establish if anything is truly done voluntarily, that's the crux of the issue...

@JMac There is no such issue. Of course you can distinguish between deciding (voluntary) and being forced (involuntary) to do something.

@PerttiRuismäki But you cant prove that what you percieve as a voluntary decision is actually "decided" by you, and not just an illusion of brain function which gives you the illusion that you could have acted differently.

@JMac There is no-one else in my head deciding my actions. I cannot prove that, but it would be quite irrational to even suspect otherwise. Someone makes my decisions anyway and I am the most usual and practically the only suspect.

@PerttiRuismäki Why are you assuming some agent is causing the apprent decisions?  You're pre-supposing freewill of some agent still, when you havent even given a way to rule out that there is no agent acting, and the perception of choice is illusory.

@JMac Can you explain, what an "illusory choice" means? What is happening in reality when this illusion is experienced?

@PerttiRuismäki The same thing that happens when we think in general.  We dont fully understand the process of thinking, and everything we do understand is just reactions in the brain.  The brain could just process all the information it has, and spit out your decision. The brain seems to control thought, as far as we know currently, and we don't know the mechanism.  You would have to prove decisions arent just a physical reaction where the result is the brain creating the thought "you decide to do this" and then you interpreting that as having will over it when it's just a set of reactions.

@JMac You don't understand thinking at all if you imagine that thinking is "just reactions in the brain". Reactions cannot make decisions. Every reaction has only one possible outcome, a decision is a deliberate selection out of multiple alternatives. Reactions cannot create anything. Reactions cannot feel or experience anything. Reactions don't have any opinions or preferences. Reactions don't strive to achieve any goals in the future. Reactions don't plan ahead or remember the past.

@PerttiRuismäki Do you have sources for any of that, besides the obvious "reactions cannot make decisions".  That's pointless to say, because again, we dont know enough about brain function to say if any decision is actually ever made.  The rest is just assertions about brain function that you surely cannot prove and have no backup for besides your own intuition.

I am making no assertions. I am only referring to the definitions of concepts and known facts.  Do you have any reason to even suspect that decisions are not actually made? How did you decide to question the very existence of decisions?

@PerttiRuismäki I dont know, because I (like everyone else) dont fully understand how the brain works.  You're pre-supposing that I "decided" to question it, but what is to say this "decision" isnt caused entirely by my physical brain makeup reacting to the physical signals it gets (such as the text I'm responding to), and giving me a sensation of "deciding"?

@JMac If you don't decide your actions, then who does? There must be a living thinking person who makes them. Decisions are not mere reactions to physical signals. Decisions are based on what you think you should do.

@PerttiRuismäki You need to link some sort of backup for the statement that decisions arent reactions to physical signals.  I'm quite sure we dont know enough about the mind and brain to make claims like that.

@JMac How about a dictionary? Look up what the word "decision" means. It is a deliberate selection of a course of action out of multiple alternatives.

@PerttiRuismäki You still have to show that we make actual decisions and dont just have an illusion that you've made a deliberate selection (and I've already elaborated on this quite a bit above, it seems almost like that comment ignored the whole conversation leading up to this).

@JMac And I have multiple times told you that decisions could not possibly be illusions. I can observe from a distance that you decided to write all these comments. Is that also an illusion?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
